# fail2ban filter for ical regex

Tags: fail2ban, regular-expressions

i am trying to get a regex for an ical service on my host working without success. This is a part of the logfile:

```
Tue Jul 23 13:55:23 2019: ical|T720] [info   ] Accepted connection from [::ffff:2.3.4.5]:56450
Tue Jul 23 13:55:23 2019: [net/[::ffff:5.6|T5234] [error  ] HrLogon server "http://localhost:123/" user "Admin": logon failed   
Tue Jul 23 13:55:23 2019: [net/[::ffff:5.6|T5234] [warning] Login failed (0x80040111 logon failed), resending authentication request   
Tue Jul 23 13:55:23 2019: [net/[::ffff:5.6|T5234] [notice ] [::ffff:5.61.48.194]:56450 - Admin [23/Jul/2019:13:55:23 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1"   
Tue Jul 23 13:55:23 2019: [net/[::ffff:5.6|T5234] [info   ] Connection closed
```

This is the part of the log file and i tried already different things to get this into a filter. The important parts are "Login failed" and in the next line the part with the IP.
But how can i get this working?
Any help would be great!!!

Thanks in advance

icey

Actual configs looking like:
ical.conf:

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]

failregex = ^*Login failed\n^.*\[notice \] \[::ffff:<HOST>\]$

ignoreregex =
[Init]
maxlines = 2
```

and the jail conf:

```
[ical]

enabled = false
port = 8443
filter = kopano-ical
logpath = /var/log/ical.log
maxtetry = 3
bantime = 3600
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! What are the "different things" you have  tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like?

Comment: Hi Jenny, thanks for your answer. The purpose is that the ip is beeing banned as in the config: 
`[ical]
enabled = false
port = 8443
filter = ical
logpath = /var/log/ical.log
maxtetry = 3
bantime = 3600`
The filter conf looks like this:
`[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]

failregex = ^*Login failed\n^.*\[notice \] \[::ffff:<HOST>\]$

ignoreregex =
[Init]
maxlines = 2`

Comment: It's very hard to read the config when it's in a comment - please instead click the "edit" link below the question, and add the config there. Then use the `{}` button to format it as code, so it will be easier to read.

Comment: hope it is better now, sorry for the trouble.. 
i tried around with several expression variants but i am not able to get the expression written that it finds the correct part in the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your regex is not correct. You're missing dot (.) at the beginning right after `^`, `.*` before `\n` and since you used `$` and the end you need to put `.*` before `$`, `]` is not the last character.

```
failregex = ^.*Login failed.*\n^.*\[notice \] \[::ffff:<HOST>\].*$
```

Comment: Thanks Ergec, it seems to work fine :) Thanks a lot!!